# Solving for the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently working on a problem in special relativity and it requires me to find the inverse of a matrix of a very specific form as follows:

Given a 4x4 matrix $A$ of the form $$A = I + a\cdot\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T$$  I need to find a matrix $B$ where $$B = I + b\cdot\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T$$ such that $$ AB = I$$

Where  $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^4$, and $I$ denotes the identity matrix. We are looking to find $b$ in terms of $a$. I tried multipliying the two expressions together but I wasn't really sure how to solve for $b$ in a matrix equation or how the outer product between $\vec{v}$ with itself plays a role in this problem.

Comment: Using the fact that $\vec{v}^T \cdot\vec{v}=v^2$ I got $$b=-\frac{a}{1+av^2}$$

Comment: Maybe you could give a link to the problem you are solving? Or elaborate a little? It's not necessary, just my personal curiosity. It's been a long time since I studied SR.

Comment: Hi @You'reInMyEye, I've solved the problem thanks to your help. But if you're interested, the problem was finding the force on a particle $\vec{f} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$ where $\vec{p} = \gamma m \vec{v}$ . It can be shown through this that the relativistic version of Newton's  second law is $$\vec{f} = \gamma m \bigg[ I + \gamma^2\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T}{c^2}\bigg]\vec{a}$$ The part of the problem was to invert this equation to find $\vec{a}$ in terms of $\vec{f}$. Which gives $$\vec{a} = \frac{1}{\gamma m} \bigg[ I - \frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T}{c^2}\bigg]\vec{f}$$ Cheers !

Comment: Thank you, David! A classical problem then, nice to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you explicitly multiply $AB$ (or $BA$, it doesn't matter), and use the fact that $$\vec{v}^T \cdot\vec{v}=v^2$$ you get

$$I+(a+b)\vec{v} \cdot\vec{v}^T+abv^2~ \vec{v} \cdot\vec{v}^T=I$$

$$a+b+abv^2=0$$

$$b=-\frac{a}{1+av^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! A question however, in the expression $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T$  does the order of operation not matter here? so that we can use the relation that the dot product gives the magnitude of $\vec{v}$

Comment: @DavidFeng, matrix product is associative, as far as I know. Meaning: $$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T \cdot \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T=\vec{v}\cdot(\vec{v}^T \cdot \vec{v})\cdot\vec{v}^T=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T) \cdot (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}^T)$$

Comment: Got it, I was carrying the point of the comment further than intended. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 9):

By Sherman-Morrison formula,

$$(I+a.\vec{v}.\vec{v}^T)^{-1}=I-\frac{a.\vec{v}.\vec{v}^T}{1+a\left\|\vec{v}\right\|^2}$$

Hence,

$$b=-\frac{a}{1+a\left\|\vec{v}\right\|^2}$$

Comment: You were faster than me. +1 Although I'll still post